# "Bridging X and Y" or "bridging X with Y"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, conjunctions

Which is the correct (or more correct) version of this phrase and why?

> 1. Bridging ancient wisdom **with** contemporary science
> 2. Bridging ancient wisdom **and** contemporary science.

Comment: Niether one of them works as a stand alone sentence. They are sentence fragments. What are you trying to say? What is the context?

Comment: Jim, the phrase is a tagline. So basically we're trying to convey that we bridge/combine ancient wisdom with modern/contemporary science. It has a locative quality to it I think...yoking wisdom to science and carrying both into the future. Because of that, I'm slightly more inclined to use "with," but since I am not very good at grammar, I wanted to ask people here!

Comment: It's not a grammatical problem but a semantic problem. You can, as Jim points out, "bridge a river with a trampoline", but you can't "bridge ancient wisdom with science": it doesn't make semantic sense. You can "bridge ancient wisdom AND science", however, because then you're **connecting** (= bridging) them. That's the point: semantics, not grammar.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that *Bridging ancient wisdom **AND** contemporary science* is the proper introductory phrase. When bridging two entities, one erects a bridge between them. The bridge is the connector. One doesn't *"bridge A **with** Z" but one "**combines** A **with** Z". Different words, different usage rules.

Comment: What about bridging a river or bridging a canyon? All of the definitions I see focus as much or more on a bridge being a structure that spans and provides a passage over something. Of course we all know that a bridge also spans between. Likewise for the verb. My point is that it isn't clear at all which is right from the information given. I might bridge a river with a trampoline (http://www.fastcodesign.com/1671052/a-trampoline-bridge-for-bouncing-across-pariss-river-seine#1) Of course that would be so much fun that I wouldn't really care where it bridges from or to.

Comment: Bridging a river with trampolines is really cool!

Comment: @Jim: Yes, but one doesn't talk about bridging ancient wisdom with contemporary science in the same way one talks about bridging a canyon to pass over the chasm or the river beneath. Sometimes analyzing the semantics of the phrase helps in the absence of a concrete context. Frankly, using "bridging ancient wisdom with contemporary science" to mean "passing over ancient wisdom with contemporary science" would demonstrate intolerable stupidity by the writer; "replacing ancient wisdom with contemporary science" seems more like it to me. One can also bridge (connect) Internet connections.

Comment: I do. But I have a vivid imagination. I'll have to overlook your pejorative reply.

Comment: 'Bridging G' requires that G be a separator (_river, channel_ ... perhaps a gap, _gorge_ ...) and as you say, 'ancient wisdom' doesn't qualify. // [R H K Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bridge) seems to license 'bridged A and B' , but I'm not happy with say 'bridged Buda and/with Pest' (**bridge**  '16. to join by or as if by a bridge')

Answer (score -1):

For me, the two phrases have very different meanings.

1. Bridging ancient wisdom with contemporary science

To me, this means that you are looking at ancient wisdom and within ancient wisdom you see two ideas X and Y. The two ideas seem disconnected. They are separated by a conceptual chasm. However, by using contemporary science, you are able to build a bridge over that chasm to connect X and Y. Now, due to the help of contemporary science we understand how X and Y inter-relate.

In other words "Bridging X with Z" means that you are constructing a bridge out of Z or by using Z in order to connect two things in X or to get over X.

2. Bridging ancient wisdom and contemporary science

To me, this means that you think there is a chasm between ancient wisdom and contemporary science. You will provide a bridge between these two domains.

In other words "Bridging X and Y" means that there are two domains X and Y that are separated by a chasm and you will build a bridge (out of unspecified material) to connect the two.

Comment: You might be overthinking this.